# node.js where is my config file?

Tags: node.js

```
$ node run.js
[Sat May 11 2013 19:13:06 GMT-0400 (EDT)] ERROR { [Error: Cannot find module './app.yaml'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
env = development
{}
env = development
{ redis: { port: 6379, host: '127.0.0.1', password: '', db: 1, options: {} } }
[ '.npmignore',
  'app.yaml',
  'config',
  'example',
  'freq.js',
  'node_modules',
  'run.js',
  'test.js',
  'whereami.js' ]
```

Output of node.js code below

```
var fs = require('fs')

fs.readdir('.', function(err, files) {
        console.log(files);
});

var config = require('yaml-config');
var env = 'development';

var settings = config.readConfig('./app.yaml');
// path from your app root without slash
console.log('env = %s', env);
console.log(settings);

settings = config.readConfig('/Users/shawn/dev/node.js/example/app.yaml');
console.log('env = %s', env);
console.log(settings);
```

Brandon, fair point. I was using the example from the npm page. I've simplified the code and combined my file system check.

Comment: I am confused.  You are changing two things at once.  In your first example, you are using the development environment with a relative path and in the second, the test environment with an absolute path.  I'm not sure clear on for what you are seeking help.

Comment: Fair point, I've edited the code and my post. Results are the same.

Comment: I do not know where the config file is. Thought I'd let you know.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the code with current working directory set to the folder where the config file resides? Ie are you running the application from within the given folder? Try to log $PWD from your code and see what that gives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues in the past with modules that dynamically 'load' config files using `require()` and a relative path.  I've only had these issues on Mac OS X, though, and never on my personal Ubuntu machine. I don't do node.js development in Windows, so I can't speak to that environment.

The problem I've encountered is that the [module loads relative](https://github.com/rjyo/yaml-config-node/blob/master/lib/yaml-config.js#L25) to where the `require()` function is invoked. Here's how you could easily solve that problem:

```
var settings = config.readConfig(require.resolve('./app.yaml'));
```

You might be able to hack something together using [path.relative](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to) just to test if passing a relative path also resolves the issue.  The path woule be relative to the location of the yaml-config module, and will most likely be something like `../../../src/app.yaml` depending on your project's structure compared to yaml-config's lib structure.

If you want to play around with the relative stuff, it would look something like this (edit: fixed parentheses below):

```
var relative = path.relative(require.resolve('yaml-config'), './app.yaml');
var settings = config.readConfig(relative);
```

Comment: I am indeed running Mac OS X and by app.yaml bombing various spots in the file structure I found that node is mapping 'app.yaml' to the node_modules directory. Thanks Jim!

Comment: Yeah, so that's definitely what it is. The recent instance of this that I remember is with mocha and a custom reporter. When I invoke mocha from the command line, it ends up looking like: `mocha --reporter ../../../../../custom-reporter`